# Why can't a CSP be set with Firebase?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, content-security-policy, firebase-hosting

I recently went through a pentest from a 3rd party company on my React.js web app, hosting on Firebase Hosting (+ Authentication, Functions, and Storage) and one of the vulnerabilities pointed out by the pentest was not having a Content Security Policy (CSP) set. I made a few attempts on setting a CSP, just as I set my others headers on `firebase.json`, but I can't seem to find a minimum setting that will actually show my app when deployed to Firebase Hosting. When I set any CSP setting, the Firebase hosted URL after a deploy is just a blank page with nothing on it. Any idea if it is possible to set a CSP without breaking my Firebase hosted app? Below are a few of my attempted settings with errors:

- `{"key": "Content-Security-Policy", "value": "default-src * data: blob: filesystem: about: ws: wss: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';"},`
- `{"key": "Content-Security-Policy", "value": "default-src *;"},`
- `{"key": "Content-Security-Policy", "value": "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' https://cdn.firebase.com https://*.firebaseio.com https://www.googletagmanager.com; object-src 'self'; connect-src  data: blob: 'unsafe-inline'; style-src:  data: blob: 'unsafe-inline'; img-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline';  media-src *; font-src data: blob: 'unsafe-inline'; frame-ancestors * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline';"`

Errors:

```
appname.web.app/:1 Refused to load the image 'https://appname.web.app/logo192.png' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src self". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

appname.web.app/:1 Refused to load the image 'https://appname.web.app/favicon.ico' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src self". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

appname.web.app/:1 Refused to load the script 'https://appname.web.app/static/js/main.abc.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src self". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

appname.web.app/:1 Refused to load the stylesheet 'https://appname.web.app/static/css/main.abc.css' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src self". Note that 'style-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

appname.app/:1 Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src self". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-aaaaaaabbbbbbbbbcccccc='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

appname.web.app/:1 Refused to load manifest from 'https://appname.web.app/manifest.json' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src self". Note that 'manifest-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

appname.web.app/:1 Refused to load the image 'https://appname.web.app/favicon.ico' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src self". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

Answer (score 1):

The errors don't match any of the attempted settings you list. Only the third instance specifies "default-src 'self'", but you also define a lot of the other directives so it should not fall back to default-src. I suspect that multiple CSPs are defined, so you first need to identify all CSPs (check response headers and meta tags) and then find out what and how other CSPs are set.

Did the pentest company specify what they expected from the CSP? Setting a policy that allows pretty much anything is quite useless, it only ticks the box. In that case it is better to start by setting a strict frame-ancestors directive. Setting a strict CSP may often require rewriting parts of the application and replacing components. There could be some steps in between where the tradeoff between the investment in the application and the increased security by CSP can make sense.

Comment: "tradeoff between the investment in the application and the increased security by CSP" is exactly where my head has been; tailoring the CSP takes some fine tuning, and not always worth the time. I am still a bit confused why setting a minimum CSP of `{"key": "Content-Security-Policy", "value": "default-src *;"},` still crashed the app. Is that not the minimum CSP? or are you saying it is `default-src 'self'`? I would need to dig into other CSPs, I didn't intentionally set any others, so maybe GCP has some default CSP?

Comment: "default  *" and "default 'self" are actually quite strict CSPs as they will not allow inline scripts or styles, eval, data:, blob:, ws, wss. A minimal CSP is really just implementing frame-ancestors to replace X-Frame-Options.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with frame-ancestors, can you elaborate on that?

Comment: It is one of the directives you can set in Content-Security-Policy, see https://content-security-policy.com/frame-ancestors/. It limits who can frame the page, but in a more flexible way than X-Frame-Options.